# vuetify.js how to get full width of v-container

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm new to `vuetify.js` and started playing around with it.

[image]

This is my code.

**Admin-panel.vue**

```
<v-content class="yellow">
  <v-container>
    <v-layout>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

**create-user.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-container class="red">
        <v-layout class="blue">
            <v-flex md12>
                form
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Here I can see `v-container` element gets the full width available.
What I want is my `v-container` inside the create-user component to get the that same width. (Yellow will disappear and red will fill the screen)

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to add the `fluid` attribute to the `<v-container fluid>`?

Comment: yes,I tired it too

Comment: Can you reproduce on [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com)? Afaics it should take full width minus the margins and/or paddings.

Comment: `<v-flex full-width>` under `<v-layout>' will push this to full width and v-flex will allow some good flexiblity on sizing other things you may not want full width.

Comment: I using `container--fluid`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use the `fluid` prop:

```html
<v-container fluid>
  <!-- content -->
</v-container>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/begueradj-the-sasster/pen/VOYObP?&editable=true&editors=101).

Comment: I'm using the same code above that he is and simply adding fluid to v-container does not fix the issue.

Comment: Which thing means your issue is somewhere else, otherwise what I shared here is mentioned in the official documentation itself @JeffBluemel

Comment: I using `container--fluid`

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue.

I realized that in my instance I had a `<v-content>` on both the parent and child page. The `<v-content>` is used to make the app look pretty and manage spacing on the nav bar and title bar.

Be sure you only have one declared in your app.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try using the margin and padding classes/props?

```
<v-container class="red ma-0">
```

or

```
<v-container class="red" :ma-0="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown">
```

for having the full screen only for mobile devices?

Answer (score 3):

The answer posted by @Billial  Begueradj is perfect. However, problem may still persist  *if there's an unchecked **v-container** tag up the hierarchy*.

**This will NOT work**

```
<v-container>
  <v-container fluid>This will not work</v-container>
<v-container>
```

In the above code, the inner **v-container** tag will not achieve full-width because there's another **v-container** tag up in the hierarchy that is not set to layout in full-width and it'll effectively limit the inner one

**This will work**

```
<v-container fluid>
  <v-container fluid> This will work </v-container>
</v-container>
```

Setting both the inner and the outer **v-container** tags to occupy full width resolves it.

Answer (score 3):

Use fluid and remove the padding if any

```html
<v-container fluid class="py-0 px-0">
  <!-- content -->
</v-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and adding fluid was not enough. It turned out that after create project in the **style.css** file, **#app had the max-width property set to 1280px;**. After changing it to width: 100% and padding: 0, it looks the way I wanted.

In style.css

```css
#app {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

to:

```css
#app {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try like this

**master.vue**

```
<v-app id="app">
<v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        temporary
        absolute
>
    <sidebar></sidebar>
</v-navigation-drawer>
<v-toolbar dark color="primary" fixed app>
    <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">MyBlog</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items>
        <v-text-field
                color="purple"
                id="globalSearch"
                name="globalSearch"
                label="Search"
                v-model="globalSearch"
                v-validate="'required'"
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-btn to="dashboard" flat>Dashboard</v-btn>
        <v-btn to="login" flat>Login</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Register</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
</v-toolbar>
<v-content>
    <v-container fluid>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
</v-content>
<v-footer height="auto">
    <v-card
            flat
            tile
            class="indigo lighten-1 white--text text-xs-center"
    >
        <v-card-text>
            <v-btn
                    v-for="icon in icons"
                    :key="icon"
                    icon
                    class="mx-3 white--text"
            >
                <v-icon size="24px">@{{ icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-text class="white--text">
            &copy;2018 â€” <strong>Eliyas Hossain</strong>
        </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
</v-footer>
</v-app>
```

**category.vue**

```
<template>
<v-card>
        <v-card-title>
            <div>
                <h2 class="pl-2">Categories</h2>
                <v-btn @click="dialog = !dialog" color="primary" dark>New Category</v-btn>
            </div>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-text-field
                    v-model="search"
                    append-icon="search"
                    label="Search"
                    single-line
                    hide-details
            ></v-text-field>
        </v-card-title>
</v-card>
</template>
```

so it will take full space in right side.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using nuxt - make sure you apply the fluid prop to the top level v-container in the layout and not the ones in your page components.

```
 <v-main>
  <v-container fluid>
    <Nuxt />
  </v-container>
</v-main>
```