# How to get dynamic width of a specific div in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get the width of a container dynamically in vue with the help of refs. But, either it is returning the previous value, or it is showing undefined. I am guessing I am doing something wrong. I just want the width of a particular div dynamically.

I referred [Vue - Setting the width of a component dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511236/vue-setting-the-width-of-a-component-dynamically), [vuetify.js how to get full width of v-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51038082/vuetify-js-how-to-get-full-width-of-v-container) and [Vue - setting width of an element equal to the width of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395866/vue-setting-width-of-an-element-equal-to-the-width-of-another-element) but no luck

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   mounted () {
    this.screenWidth()
   },
   methods: {
     screenWidth() {
      console.log("screen", this.$refs.container?.offsetWidth);
      return `${this.$refs?.container?.offsetWidth}`;
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" ref="container">
   Screen {{ screenWidth() }}
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `ref="container"` in the code you posted, so you can't expect a ref to exist

Comment: I am extremely sorry @EstusFlask. I added the ref. Can you check now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of [Vue JS - How to get window size whenever it changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380830/vue-js-how-to-get-window-size-whenever-it-changes) 's accepted answer, you can add a `mounted()` call always to have the width.

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
    return {
      sWidth: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.screenWidth);
  },
  mounted () {
    this.screenWidth()
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.screenWidth);
  },
  methods: {
    screenWidth() {
      this.sWidth = this.$refs.container?.offsetWidth;
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" ref="container">
    screen {{ sWidth }}
</div>
```

Comment: I think this answer is only valid for the very specific case in which the container div corresponds to the whole window and reacts to a window resizing. If there is a container nested in another element whose size changes dynamically (e.g. due to changing content), another strategy is needed.